# How to dynamically add a group of buttons to android app - With categories

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm a beginner to android and am working on an app to organize a chore counting system and I'm having some issues with my next step. I am trying to give users the option to input different chores at their choice within the app (ideally they would start with no chores then input them on their own). For each chore they enter, 4 new elements need to show up (the name of chore, increase arrow, decrease arrow and chore count number). I am also trying to keep those new additions organized based on if they fall under "*kitchen, bathroom or general*" (user would select that when they add the chore). I tried to use groups and tags but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

```
`package com.example.testbasic;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int integer = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void increase(View view) {
        integer = integer + 1;
        System.out.println(view.getTag());
        display(integer);


    }
    public void decrease(View view) {
        integer = integer - 1;
        System.out.println(view.getTag());
        display(integer);
    }

    private void display(int number) {
        TextView displayInteger = findViewById(R.id.integer_number);
        displayInteger.setText("" + number);
    }
}
`
```

Snip of the XML layout
'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/welcome_to_the_chore_calculator"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Kitchen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="@string/kitchen" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
                android:id="@+id/EmptyDishRackG"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="tv_EmptyDishRack,IncreaseEDR,DecreaseEDR,integer_numberEDR" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_EmptyDishRack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Kitchen"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:drawablePadding="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/empty_dish_rack"
                android:padding="12dp"
                tools:ignore="UseCompatTextViewDrawableXml" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/IncreaseEDR"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_EmptyDishRack"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:onClick="increase"
                android:tag="EmptyDishRack"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
                tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/DecreaseEDR"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_EmptyDishRack"
                android:layout_marginStart="-140dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_EmptyDishRack"
                android:onClick="decrease"
                android:tag="EmptyDishRack"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
                tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/integer_numberEDR"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_EmptyDishRack"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_EmptyDishRack"
                android:layout_marginStart="-31dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/IncreaseEDR"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/DecreaseEDR"
                android:text="@string/_0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp" />'
```

Here is how it looks so far

[Up and down arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPVRF.jpg)
[Other categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY7lJ.jpg)

*^the chores that are currently there are just examples users may have different ones*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Recycler view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Faizan says, a RecyclerView is probably the best option here. RecyclerView lets you have a list of items (your chores in this case) stored in an ArrayList.

You set up how the items will display in the RecyclerView. This is done using a ViewHolder. In your case the ViewHolder will have the name of the chore, the up/down arrows and the count of chores.

Because the RecyclerView is linked to your ArrayList, each chore will display automatically in its own ViewHolder. You can then update the Array with new items as the user adds them. Here is a link to an example:

http://www.digitstory.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/android_recyclerview.jpg

For more details, have a look here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

To get started, you could try YouTube and seach for "RecyclerView Android Studio". Work through a few example tutorials to get the concept, and try to adapt them to your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll give that a try!

Comment: No worries, if it helps you please could you click to accept my answer as the best answer, it helps both you and I earn reputation on stack overflow. Cheers, let me know how you get on!